# Jquery Validate dropdown required if field empty

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm trying to make the dropdown required if the #category field is empty.

Thanks!

JQUERY ATTEMPT #1:

```
$("#uploadDocsForm").validate({
    rules: {
        name: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 2,
            maxlength: 255  
        },
        cat_id: {
            required: function(element) {
                return $("#category").val() == '';
            }
        }
    },
    messages: {
        name: 'Please enter a <b>Document Name</b>.',
        cat_id: 'Please select a <b>Category</b>.'
    }
});
```

JQUERY ATTEMPT #2:

```
$("#uploadDocsForm").validate({
    rules: {
        name: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 2,
            maxlength: 255  
        },
        cat_id: {
            required: {
                depends: function(element) {
                    return $("#category").val() == '';
                }
            }
        }
    },
    messages: {
        name: 'Please enter a <b>Document Name</b>.',
        cat_id: 'Please select a <b>Category</b>.'
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<form name="uploadDocsForm" id="uploadDocsForm">   
    <label for="name">Document Name</label>
    <input name="name" id="name" type="text" class="textbox"/>
    <label for="cat_id">Category</label>
    <select name="cat_id" id="cat_id" class="dropdown">
    <option selected>Please Select Category</option>
    <option>------------------------</option>
    <option value="1">test cat</option>
    </select>
    <label for="category">New Category</label>
    <input name="category" id="category" type="text" class="textbox"/>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
$("#uploadDocsForm").validate({
    rules: {
        name: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 2,
            maxlength: 255  
        },
        cat_id: {
            required: {
                depends: function(element) {
                    return $("#category").val() == '';
                }
            }
        }
    },
    messages: {
        name: 'Please enter a <b>Document Name</b>.',
        cat_id: 'Please select a <b>Category</b>.'
    }
});
```

The depends function now checks if the category element is filled, and if so the second is required. Otherwise it is optional (meaning can be filled).

Use Cases:

- Category filled, cat_id empty  : invalid
- Category filled, cat_id filled : valid
- Category empty, cat_id empty   : valid
- Category empty, cat_id filled  : valid

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working properly. I tried this as well: cat_id: {
 required: {
  depends: function(element) {
   return ($("#category").val() != '' && $(element).val() != '');
  }
 }
}

Comment: Your suggestion didn't trigger the existing errors (if name is empty) but when I added the "required" portion it still triggered the name errors but didn't write any message for the cat_id. It seemed to be "working" but the error message is suppressed.

Comment: @Stephen I have corrected the code in accordance to the [this source](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate) in the `rules` section. If it still does not work, set up a jsFiddle for us to use because this should work. In other words, your second attempt seems correct, if thats not working put up a jsFiddle.

Comment: I decided to do a bit more research and found the issue! all i had to do was add value="" to the empty options -- thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

I appears that 'depends' is not supported anymore.

I used the following and it works:

```
<form name="uploadDocsForm" id="uploadDocsForm">   
    <label for="name">Document Name</label>
    <input name="name" id="name" type="text" class="textbox"/>
    <label for="cat_id">Category</label>
    <select name="cat_id" id="cat_id" class="dropdown">
    <option value="" selected>Please Select Category</option>
    <option>------------------------</option>
    <option value="1">test cat</option>
    </select>
    <label for="category">New Category</label>
    <input name="category" id="category" type="text" class="textbox"/>
    </form>
```

Notice the **option value=""** which cause the validation to fail since val is empty

```
$("#uploadDocsForm").validate({
    rules: {
        name: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 2,
            maxlength: 255  
        },
        cat_id: {
            required: true
            }
        }
    },
    messages: {
        name: 'Please enter a <b>Document Name</b>.',
        cat_id: 'Please select a <b>Category</b>.'
    }
});
```

Comment: Works for me, too. The depends and return values no longer needed as long as you have a blank option by default! Cheers, David.