# Is it possible to use jQuery.validVal to validate select dropdown list?

Tags: jquery, validation, html-select

I'm using [jQuery.validVal](http://validval.frebsite.nl/) to validate a form. And it works fine for all input fields, but I can't get it to work on select lists. And I can't seem to find any documentation of it working or how to get it to work.

Anyone have any experience with validVal and select lists?

Code example of select list:

```
<select required>
  <option value="">Dropdown title</option>
  <option value="Value1">Valuetext1</option>
  <option value="Value2">Valuetext2</option>
  <option value="Value3">Valuetext3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey Please Refer This Link

The Sample code is

```
<form name="uploadDocsForm" id="uploadDocsForm">   
<label for="name">Document Name</label>
<input name="name" id="name" type="text" class="textbox"/>
<label for="cat_id">Category</label>
<select name="cat_id" id="cat_id" class="dropdown">
<option selected>Please Select Category</option>
<option>------------------------</option>
<option value="1">test cat</option>
</select>
<label for="category">New Category</label>
<input name="category" id="category" type="text" class="textbox"/>
</form>
```

Js Code is

```
$("#uploadDocsForm").validate({
rules: {
    name: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 2,
        maxlength: 255  
    },
    cat_id: {
        required: {
            depends: function(element) {
                return $("#category").val() == '';
            }
        }
    }
},
messages: {
    name: 'Please enter a <b>Document Name</b>.',
    cat_id: 'Please select a <b>Category</b>.'
}
```

});

[Reference Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5957440/jquery-validate-dropdown-required-if-field-empty)

Hope It will works for you

Comment: Thanks. I'll check that out in a bit. I'll report back and mark as answer. :)

Comment: Am I right that you have based this example on [jquery validate](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) and not [jquery.validval](http://validval.frebsite.nl/)?

The thing is that everything else works with validval, error messages, form submission, etc. So I would really like to get it to work with validVal