# ASP.NET Dropdown Autopostback failing on jQuery Validation errors

Tags: jquery, asp.net, postback

We have a SP2010 site where validation is done using the jquery validate plugin. In a custom WebPart the layout has few common fields, a dropdown and multiple panels which load based on the value selected in the dropdown. The issue is that in case someone clicks on save first and there are validation errors(required field) validation the OnSelectedIndexChanged stops firing.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Multiple panels, each with a save and close button:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit1" runat="server" Text="Save" onclick="btnSubmit1_Click" />
<asp:Button ID="btnClose1" runat="server" CssClass="cancel" CausesValidation="false" Text="Close" onclick="btnClose1_Click" />
```

Script- jQuery Validation:

```
$("form").validate({
rules:{
REQUIRED VALIDATION RULES FOR MULTIPLE FIELDS
}
});
```

After page load, the dropdown posts back just fine as long as no errors have occurred but once there are validation errors then even after the errors are corrected the page does not post back on the change of dropdown.

Really appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Please use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5957440/jquery-validate-dropdown-required-if-field-empty URL I think it will help you

Comment: Hi Yogesh, Thanks for the reply but this dropdown is not a required field and for other fields the validation is working fine. The problem is that the postback to the server is failing as soon as validation errors(due to other fields) appear on the page.

Comment: did you try causevalidation=false

Comment: Hi Michael, the causesvalidation="false" did not work. still the validation error are stopping the postback.

Comment: Hi Ehsan, I added validation group to the fields to be validated but the problem persists